# Deleting old questions versus GDPR

Tags: support

Trying to delete a question I asked some time ago, as I don't feel comfortable sharing its content anymore, I encountered this alert:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.

Is it still valid, according to the new GDPR data restrictions? I would really like the question to go. What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310326/369802) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310348/369802) post on main meta (and the comments on those posts) seem to say that the GDPR doesn't act on the level of treating a question or answer as 'personal data'. So, being unable to delete your question because [it doesn't meet the criteria to allow you to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369802) does not seem to be a violation of the GDPR.

Usually, the way to go about such things is [to request dissociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/369802) of the post from your main account:

> If you would like to have your name dissociated from one of your posts, you can request we do so by clicking on the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page. Your username will no longer be linked, the username will be shown as "anon", and you will no longer earn any reputation from the post. All reputation you had previously gained/lost from the post will also be reversed, and badges you earned from the post may be revoked.

Looking at your account though, it seems likely such a request may end up being declined, as this is your only post on IPS and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997/369802) seems to suggest that [deleting your account on IPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) might be favorable if you want to be dissociated of 100% of your posts on this site:

> If you request that a large percentage of your posts be disassociated from your account, we might request that you simply request account deletion (which attributes your posts to an anonymous user), and start over.

In this case, deletion may be favorable because otherwise the question is still traceable to your account through this meta post.

Comment: Technically, SE is obligated to accept dissociation requests, since the Creative Commons license SE uses requires it.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a lawyer, so talk to a lawyer if you want to be sure, but:

GDPR is about personally identifiable data, such as your e-mail address. It doesn't apply to the questions and answers you post on the site.

If you would like you can disassociate your account from that question so that your username will not be seen there. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0) for more. But the question itself will stay.

[Mods can redact data from the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or). If there is a pressing need for data to be redacted you can flag more moderator attention and ask for redaction.

Comment: The question specifically gives personal medical details about the OP's girlfriend... I'm not actually sure that isn't covered by GDPR.

Comment: @Catija There is no connection to the girlfriend. You could maybe make a case if the OP was offering information about the real name and place of living of his girlfriend that the medical condition is personally identifiable data that can be connected to her. But then you already have lots of personally identifiable data at hands... If you, as a mod, think that the data shouldn't be openly visible you can redact the data to help OP. In the linked example for redaction it says "user who posted actual medical records" as an example.